# Where did I go wrong with this differential equation?

Tags: calculus

I got the following formula: $$m*\frac{dv}{dt} = -k*v²$$
where m and k are constants.

These where my steps to solve it:
 $$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{-k*v²}{m}$$
$$m*dv=-k*v²dt$$
$$\frac{1}{-k*v²}dv = \frac{1}{m}dt$$
Integrate both sides:
$\int\frac{1}{-k*v²}dv = \int\frac{1}{m}dt$
Since m &k are constants:
$\frac{-1}{k}*\int\frac{1}{v²}dv = \frac{1}{m}*\int1*dt$
$$\frac{-1}{k}*\frac{-1}{v} + C_1= \frac{1}{m}*t + C_2$$
Let's make both C's one variable: C
$$\frac{1}{kv}= \frac{t}{m}+ C$$
Now let's inverse both sides:
$$kv = \frac{m}{t+cm}$$
$$v=\frac{m}{kt+cmk}$$
[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=m*dv%2Fdt%20%3D%20-k*v(t)%C2%B2) gives this answer but without the k in cmk and with a - in front of the right side of the equation. When I fill the equation back into the original formula I also don't get the same answer. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You do get the same as Wolframalpha, the $c_1$ there is simply $c_1=-kc$.

Comment: And if $c$ is a constant $cmk$ is another one (which will be fixed by a condition).

Comment: But why doesn't wolfram alpha show that?

Comment: It simply separated the equation different then you did (it also moved $k$ to the left). Doing so slighty changes the look of the solution, but it's still the same thing.

Comment: But shouldn't it atleast tell me what c_1 is?

Comment: You took $c2-c1 = c$ and this may be positive or negative , so hardly matters ,as WAlpha would have taken $c1- c2 = c$(his) , so gets a - sign.

Comment: But why do they say -kt, while I have +kt?

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer not to use integration constants when solving differential equation (see confusion above). Rather, I would write the following

$$-\frac{1}{k}\int_{\nu(t_0)}^{\nu(t)}\frac{d\nu'}{(\nu')^2} = \frac{1}{m}\int_{t_0}^t dt'. $$

This leads to
$$\nu(t) = \frac{m \nu(t_0)}{m + k \nu(t_0)(t-t_0)} $$

and there is no ambiguity whatsoever about ''choosing'' the constants of integration.

Comment: But can you define the limits like that?

Comment: Yes. I am free to chose where I integrate over. If I choose to integrate $t'$ between $t_0$ and $t$, then we must integrate $\nu'$ between $\nu(t_0)$ and $\nu(t)$. You can do this without ambiguity since your differential equation tells you from the start that $\nu$ is injective...